# Zend\Mail headers: Call to a member function setType() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework

When trying to set content-type in Zend\Mail message:

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
.
.
.
// create the message
$message = new Message();
$message->getHeaders()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative');
.
.
.
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setType() on a non-object in /var/www/jt_sso/website/app/library/Mail/Manager.php on line 125
```

Is there something I should do if this header is missing. I notice Zend\Mail\Headers (result of getHeaders() ) has a ::has(headerName) method so I could check if this method exists, but I can't see a method to set a new header if it's missing. Also, can't I just set the message (and create one if it doesn't exist)? When I look at examples online, I just see the get()->setType(..) method chain.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening becuase the header 'content-type' is not defined, so you have to define it.

For example :

```
$message->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('content-type', 'multipart/alternative');
```

This should add the missing header and set the 
type you want for it.